# Do I need to add bootstrap.min.css in index.html to use ng-bootstrap?

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using [angular-cli@webpack](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/WEBPACK_UPDATE.md) version with [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) (**not** [ng2-bootstrap](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap)). I did the following to my angular-cli project:

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Then followed by adding this to my file:

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

Then I added this to index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Great it is all working. My question:

**(Part 1) Do I really have to add bootstrap.min.css in index.html? Can I don't add bootstrap.css to index.html and still use ng-boostrap?**

**(Part 2) If no, then why can't ng-bootstrap just include bootstrap.css in their setup and so I don't need to add it to index.html?**

Comment: 1) have you tried it? 2) because people might want to use a custom bootstrap.css file.

Comment: I have tried not adding bootstrap.css to index.html. Ng-bootstrap doesn't work. I'm just curious why doesn't ng-bootstrap include bootstrap.css in their setup. I think got the answer from you. It's because some people might want to use a custom bootstrap.css file. Nice one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure wheather you have checked there official [page](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started), it clearly that for the time being there are 2 dependencies :

1. angular version
2. bootstrap css

> Dependencies This repository contains a set of native Angular 2
>   directives based on Bootstrap's markup and CSS. As a result no
>   dependency on jQuery or Bootstrap's JavaScript is required. The only
>   required dependencies are:
>
> Angular (requires Angular version 2 or higher, tested with 2.0-rc.5)
>   Bootstrap CSS (tested with version 4.0 alpha V3)

edit : from logical prospective: **because people might want to use a custom bootstrap.css file.**
as mentioned by @juhana

Comment: Yes I read the page. I was just wondering why can't it include bootstrap css in the setup of ng-bootstrap? I am coming from the learning perspective.

Comment: I just the answer from @Juhana. People might want to use a custom bootstrap.css

Comment: There is nothing about -integration- of ng-bootstrap on the linked page. That's why people are asking this question.